# External Monitor appears low resolution

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, resolution

I have connected a 21:9 external monitor to my 2017 MBP w/ Touch Bar through a usb-c to hdmi adaptor. The display appears blurry and almost like low resolution scaled up, does anyone know of any fixes? The display looks perfectly sharp when I connect to it with my windows PC.

Monitor model: [LG 29EA73 29 inch 21:9 UltraWide IPS Monitor](https://www.amazon.co.uk/LG-29EA73-29-inch-UltraWide/dp/B00GFP9QF4)

This is the USB-C to HDMI adaptor I'm using: https://www.amazon.co.uk/uni-Adapter-Discount-Compatible-MacBook/dp/B075V68NVR/ref=sr_1_6?keywords=usb+c+to+hdmi+adapter&qid=1583099211&s=computers&sr=1-6

Comment: What is the scaling resolution set to in System Preferences > Displays?

Comment: Are you extending the display to the new monitor, or mirroring the main display to the external? If that latter, the external display will match resolution of the main display.

Comment: Are you taking into account that the LG has a vastly lower resolution [2560x1080 vs 2880x1800] in a much larger screen area. It will never be as sharp as the Mac screen.

Comment: Yes I'm taking into account it won't be as sharp as the Mac's screen, but it looks much sharper on my windows PC.

Comment: I've tried both, mirroring and extending. In System preferences I set the resolution to my monitor's 2560x1080.